# Error in hardhat config file

Tags: hardhat

I am having an issue with smart contract deployment using hardhat. I don't see where is the error coming from. I have defined the `.env` file with values and also correctly called those values using `process.env`
here is my hardhat.config file :

````
require('dotenv').config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./artifacts",

  },

  networks: {
    goerli: {
      chainId: 5,
    },
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.API_URL ,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] ,
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.0",
}; ```
````

Comment: this is the error : Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)

Comment: Why are you defining Goerli twice?

Comment: hi @OlivierD i was advised to add goerli chain ID, i just removed it, but still i get the error

Comment: You can add the chainId, but put it all inside one. No reason for you to have 2 “goerli”. Also, what’s in your process.env? Obviously, don’t share private keys!

Comment: so what do you think courses the error?

Comment: i have the api url and the private key

Comment: That’s what I’m trying to figure out. You do have an API key that looks like that? goerli: {
      url: "https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcde"
}

Comment: Yes it like this : "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that the specific node you are trying to use to access the blockchain could be down or not available....
But before you assume that, try running whatever task you are doing using your local node and if it works then your online node must be down
In my case, I got the error

```
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

and I solved it by changing the goerli_rpc_url in my environment variable from an alchemy supplied one to one from infuria
from

> rpc_url=https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/2xAXsdfsadkflasdfaskdfhrandom

## to

> rpc_url=https://goerli.infura.io/v3/randomsdfkalsdfjrandom